# Creating spreadsheets with Google Spreadsheet api gem - is there a better way than using hashes?

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-api-ruby-client

I'm following the [google guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) and want to create a spreadsheet with populated cells. I've played with API Explorer and got the following working request body:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "startRow": 0,
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "foo"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "startRow": 1,
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 10
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I pass it as arguement it gives expected result(i.e. creates spreadsheet with data):

```
request_body = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::Spreadsheet.new(the_request_hash)
response = service.create_spreadsheet(request_body)
```

Is there a better and more readable way to create populated spreadsheets using ruby?

Comment: The shown data structure would be trivial to construct from any kind of tabular data. What are your having trouble with?

Comment: I know it's pretty simple and I've already solved the thing I wanted to accomplish. I was just wandering whether there is a more elegant way to do this. Cheers.